# TINA TI Zener diode scheme

Tags: diodes, zener, semiconductors, tina

I've encountered some problems while trying to get this scheme.
I don't think graph should look like this.
What I am trying is to draw a diagram to record the static characteristic of the Zener diode for
a) direct polarity
b) reverse polarity
c) both of these for temperatures -10, 20, 50, 80 and 110°C

[image]
[image]

Here is the diagram I got for direct polarity.

I used Analysis → DC Analysis → DC Transfer Characteristic
while setting V1's value from 0 to 1 V.

Two last images are from the similar example and everything worked well
[image]
[image]

I am a beginner (student) as you can see but willing to learn. Thank you for answers (if there'll be any)

Comment: You want answers then ask a question.

Comment: Where did you find the zener diode model? What is the expected zener/avalanche voltage?